# Designing a 3D room in openSceneGraph

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, openscenegraph

I have just started learning OpenSceneGraph and I'm trying to simulate moving around in a 3d room (walk-through in a house).

My idea is to draw closed rectangular cubes as walls and something similar for floors and ceiling and then position the camera inside the room. 
I would like to place objects inside the room like walls, doors, sofas etc inside the room. Can anyone give me an example/ideas to render a 3D room model in OpenSceneGraph.

Answer (score 1):

There is a "first person navigator" available in OSG that mimics the interaction of most FPS shooter games.

To achieve all of what you want you will probably need some kind of collision detection as well. OSG has ray-intersection code that can tell you if you are standing on an object and if you have run into something.

Rendering a room is no different than rendering anything else really, so there aren't any specific demos. Try osgEdit:
http://osgedit.sourceforge.net/

as a way to assemble objects into a scene that you can then play with.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the openscenegraph website. Here:
http://www.openscenegraph.org/index.php/documentation/getting-started

Comment: Hi, I've taken a look at the examples however I'm not sure how to achieve 3D room navigation (which is so common in games and virtual reality) so I was wondering if an example exists or any hints to design this as I'm quite noob to this world. Thanks